# Cron Running @reboot jobs

Tags: cron, reboot

I have Debian 8. Sometime when I run command the VPS got offline. From logs I see:

```
Nov 14 07:22:34 localhost cron[386]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. It only indicates that your server has *probably* been restarted and your Cron daemon is running the jobs scheduled with a non-standard macro `@reboot`.

The `@reboot` is defined in FreeBSD's [`man crontab(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab%285%29) as *Run once, at startup of cron*.  This naming works well in practice, because typically there's no need to restart Cron i.e. the startup of Cron indicates machine boot quite well. However, if the Cron actually was restarted, you'd need to look at the other `syslog` lines before and after this to be sure. Or run `last -x shutdown reboot`.